# How to construct a hash of hashes

Tags: perl, foreach, hash, hash-of-hashes

I need to compare two hashes, but I can't get the inner set of keys...

```
my %HASH = ('first'=>{'A'=>50, 'B'=>40, 'C'=>30},
            'second'=>{'A'=>-30, 'B'=>-15, 'C'=>9});
foreach my $key (keys(%HASH))
{
   my %innerhash = $options{$key};
   foreach my $inner (keys(%innerhash))
   {
      print "Match: ".$otherhash{$key}->{$inner}." ".$HASH{$key}->{$inner};
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$options{$key}` is a scalar (you can tell be the leading `$` sigil). You want to "dereference" it to use it as a hash:

```
my %HASH = ('first'=>{'A'=>50, 'B'=>40, 'C'=>30},
            'second'=>{'A'=>-30, 'B'=>-15, 'C'=>9});
foreach my $key (keys(%HASH))
{
   my %innerhash = %{ $options{$key} };  # <---- note %{} cast
   foreach my $inner (keys(%innerhash))
   {
      print "Match: ".$otherhash{$key}->{$inner}." ".$HASH{$key}->{$inner};
   }
}
```

When you're ready to really dive into these things, see [`perllol`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perllol), [`perldsc`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perldsc) and [`perlref`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlref).

Comment: I had no idea you could cast a variable in PERL, thanks so much!

Comment: @mob's answer is an application of "Use Rule 1" in "perldoc perlreftut" so you should start with that doc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you say "options" there where you mean "HASH"?

Hashes only store scalars, not other hashes; each value of %HASH is a hash reference that needs to be dereferenced, so your inner loop should be:

```
foreach my $inner (keys(%{ $HASH{$key} })
```

Or:

```
my %HASH = ('first'=>{'A'=>50, 'B'=>40, 'C'=>30},
            'second'=>{'A'=>-30, 'B'=>-15, 'C'=>9});
foreach my $key (keys(%HASH))
{
    my $innerhash = $HASH{$key};
    foreach my $inner (keys(%$innerhash))
    {
        print "Match: ".$otherhash{$key}->{$inner}." ".$innerhash->{$inner};
    }
}
```